# Select ... for update vs select on large amount of data

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume a huge table with several hundred million records and columns are well indexed. Is there any performance concern between

```
SELECT * from HUGE_TABLE where ... AND ... FOR UPDATE
```

and

```
SELECT * from HUGE_TABLE where ... AND ...
```

the main reason for the `FOR UPDATE` clause is because we may have several instance of the application running the same query at same time, but need to avoid update conflicts.

At this point is there I concern about two performance issue: 1. if there is no other query running, is `select for update` slower?. 2. if there are many other active query to `select / update` on the huge table, what will be the performance to this entire situation on this table (also update in the question)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You're asking whether there is a performance difference between the two but then you say that you observe a performance difference because the `for update` version introduces blocking and serialization for the locks.  So it seems that you already know that there is a performance difference...

Comment: How is for update on a select statement going to avoid update conflicts

Comment: @Justin Cave Thanks, actually I concern about two performance issue: 1. if there is no other query running, is `select for update` slower?. 2. if there are many other active query to `select / update` on the huge table, what will be the performance to this entire situation on this table (also update in the question)

Comment: @Paparazzi we run multiple queries in a transaction, and there can bu multiple transactions concurrently running. Optimistic locking is may be better but it's a huge change cannot afford

Comment: Still don't get how update on a select statement going to avoid update conflicts and I am sorry I asked.

Comment: @Paparazzi `select for update` lock the row to avoid other concurrent transactions to update it?

Comment: No kidding it will block updates for the duration of the transaction.  Still don't get how that avoids update conflicts (the the stated question).

Comment: What exactly are you worried about? What do you mean by update conflict?  Are you worried that a concurrent update will affect the result of your long-running select statement? Something else?

Comment: @sstan It is not my question.

Comment: @Paparazzi: ok.

Comment: Wow. You need to understand oracle WAY better. Select for update generates redo recs, so there is a perf penalty there: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:44798632736844.      And oracle provides read consistent image to all queries regardless of updates. But if you lock all those recs, you will cause all conflicting updates to block.  Take a look at tom kyte book expert oracle DB architecture - specifically chap 1 - and chap on transactions. You may want to redesign the app.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` creates at least two performance issues compared to a regular `SELECT`:

1. **Blocking other sessions.** This is a bit obvious and you already understand this, but it's worth mentioning that of course creating more locks can cause performance issues.  The good news is that Oracle never escalates locks, so it will only lock exactly what you ask it too.
2. **Writing lock data.**  The `FOR UPDATE` works by making a small update to each relevant block.  It acts like a regular change in some ways, and will create redo and undo records as you can see by running queries like `select used_urec from gv$transaction;`.  Depending on how many rows are locked, this could be significantly more expensive than a regular `SELECT`, even if no other sessions are involved.